# How to remove extended stats in a table in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Created n-distinct extended stats on tbl tale.

CREATE STATISTICS s2 (ndistinct) on col1, col2 from tbl;

Now i want to remove these stats.

Answer (score 1):

You use [drop statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropstatistics.html) for that:

```
drop statistics s2;
```